# Keep connection to SQL Server in powershell while script is working

Tags: sql-server, powershell

i have problem with temp tables  which created on SQL Server from powershell, they disappear because powershell don't keep session with SQL Server while executing script. I'm using Invoke-SQLcmd for connection.

````
$query_cd="CREATE TABLE ##Data(
             [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
             [field_group_id] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
             [name] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
             [additional_info] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
             [description] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
                ) "
Invoke-SQLcmd -ServerInstance 'someinstance,1433' -query $query_cd -U user -P pass -Database tempdb -ConnectionTimeout 0 -QueryTimeout 0 ```
````

Comment: Don't use temp tables. Or do more statements in one script (`Invoke-SqlCmd` accepts batches separated with `GO`, because it imitates `sqlcmd`). Or don't use `Invoke-SqlCmd` but create `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommmand` instances yourself.

Comment: *"they disappear"* That is by design; temporary objects (suffixed with a single `#`) last for as long as the scope that defined them does. "Global" temporary objects *can* last longer, as they persist for as long as the scope that defined them *or* when other all tasks (which is a single statement) using the object complete; which ever is later. As you just create the object, then it is immediately dropped when your connection closes and the scope ends.

Comment: @JeroenMostert `Invoke-SqlCmd` doesn't accept `GO` but you can just pass multiple query strings in an array to get the same thing

Comment: @Charlieface: are we talking about the same [`Invoke-Sqlcmd`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/sqlserver/invoke-sqlcmd) here? The one thing it has going for it (and it surely isn't much) is that it accepts `GO` for batch separation. I would much rather have support for proper parameterization rather than a poor imitation of what `sqlcmd` does, but that's another matter.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Not sure, [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/invoke-sqlcmd?view=sqlserver-ps) are contradictory `This cmdlet also accepts many of the commands supported natively by SQLCMD, such as GO and QUIT.` and `Do not specify the sqlcmd GO separator.`

Comment: @Charlieface What a mess. Sadly I don't have access to an actual instance right now or I'd test. The examples even include a script that uses `GO`. I suspect that the docs are trying to say that you can use semicolon-separated queries, but if you do, `GO` is not accepted as it's not a query -- even `sqlcmd` only accepts `GO` on a line by its own.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, You are right about this SqlConnection class but if I'am  put SqlConnection  into function I have same problem - powershell not holding connection and closes it after execution function and drop temp tables  while script working.

Comment: Well yes -- so make sure to pass the `SqlConnection` as a parameter to those functions that need to work together, with only the outer function creating an `SqlConnection`. Or, as per the `GO` advice, make a function that takes multiple statements in an array that all execute on the same connection, and/or accepts a pipeline of statements.